# Question regarding Zeta function representation

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

We know the following from Euler product:

> $$\sum_{n,p}\frac{1}{n(p)^{nz}}= \log(\zeta(z))$$

> $$\sum_{n,p} \frac{\log p}{p^{nz}} = -\frac{\zeta'(z)}{\zeta(z)}
> $$

I want to find the alternate representation for the following sum:

> $$\sum_{n,p}\frac{\log(p)}{n(ap)^{nz}}$$

Here '$a$' is a constant greater than 1

> What is the  representation of above sum in terms of Zeta and other allied function?

Answer (score 2):

The first formula is incorrect: it's halfway in between
$$
\sum_{p^n} \frac1{np^{nz}} = \log\zeta(z) \quad\text{and}\quad
\sum_{p^n} \frac{\log p}{p^{nz}} = -\frac{\zeta'(z)}{\zeta(z)}
$$
for $\Re z>1$. Analogous to the first formula, we would have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{p^n} \frac1{n(ap)^{nz}} &= \sum_p \log\big( 1-(ap)^{-z} \big)^{-1} \\
&= \log \prod_p \big( 1-(ap)^{-z} \big)^{-1} = \log \sum_{n=1}^\infty \big( a^{-\Omega(n)}n \big)^{-z}
\end{align*}
in the same half-plane, where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of prime factors of $n$ counted with multiplicity.

Comment: Made error while copy-pasting